# Запятая перед "будто"

Tags: пунктуация

"В доме они ведут себя (?) будто хозяева."
Нужна ли тут запятая?
"Будто" в данном случае частица или союз?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятая не нужна, так как *будто хозяева* входит в состав сказуемого, оно не имеет смысла без оборота с *будто*. Смысловое ударение на обороте *будто хозяева*. Будто здесь - союз, синоним *как*.